# How to create a shrinkable index bar like in the contacts app?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create an indexbar like the one in the contacts app. My code:

```
let indexBarTitles = ["#","A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

override func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    return self.indexBarTitles
}
```

The indexbar does not look like expected on smaller screens (3.5"). Whereas in the contacts app the indexbar is shrinked and contains dots, mine does not contain any and is not shrinked.

Any idea how to do this?

**Edit:**

This is what it looks like:

[image]

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: You can include a visual aid of the UI you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, it was not shrinked because the tab bar was missing. When the `indexBarTitles` array is longer it does get shrinked and looks like the contacts app.

Comment: @AMomchilov I believe you have to wait a day before being able to accept a self-answer

Comment: Two days to be precise. ;)